# Call a worksheet in a different workbook than activesheet: error

Tags: excel, vba

I need to call a worksheet("Base") in a different workbook("draft1"), while working on my active sheet. Both the active workbook("draft2") and the workbook that need to be called have a worksheet "Base" but I specifically need the worksheet in draft1.
The following works, however uses the "Base" sheet in the active sheet (since workbook hasn't been specified) and returns no error.

```
Set C = Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
```

However, when I use the following, I get a compilation error and the macro is stopped midway. Both files are saved in the same folder so this shouldn't be a problem. However, even when I call the workbook with its full address, the same error is returned. Do I perhaps need to shift the macro to the personal project thing so it can use other workbooks?

```
Set C = Workbooks("draft1.xlsx").Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
```

Help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Here's the code snippet for the above-

```
Sub CreateNewMonth()
Dim i As Integer, C As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = 1
Do While i <> 0
    Set C = Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
    'Workbooks("draft1.xlsx").
    If IsEmpty(C) = False Then
        .
        .
        .
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

There isn't any error with the loop since it is working just fine with the active sheet's "Base".

Comment: Is `"draft1.xlsx"` open when you execute that line?

Comment: It would help, if you show us the complete code part

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it isn't. Does it need to be open?

Comment: @Ike Okay, I'll edit and add the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work:

```
Set C = Workbooks("draft1.xlsx").Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
```

the file `draft1.xlsx` needs to be open.

Or you need to open it using the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open):

```
Dim wbDraft As Workbook
Set wbDraft = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\FullPathToFile\draft1.xlsx")

Dim C As Range
Set C = wbDraft.Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
```

In the end you can close the workbook using:

```
wbDraft.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Note that the workbook the code is written in can be addressed with `ThisWorkbook` easily.

Comment: Does this fail if I need to work on both the activesheet and this Base file simultaenously (they are in different workbooks)?

Comment: I used your first code, kept draft1 open and ran the macro in draft2 as well as a new presaved .xlsm file. However, it shows subscript out of range and breaks at the above codeline in the new file but works perfectly in draft2. I don't see why this is happening, the macro has been saved in the personal workbook folder so it should work globally on my device. Please help!

Comment: @zaira Please note that we cannot answer questions in comments. The answer was for your original question. If you have a new question open up a new post, show the exact code you use and explain where you get stuck or errors.